# Mystery in Ruby sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following Sinatra code:

```
post '/bucket' do
  # determine if this call is coming from filling out web form
  is_html = request.content_type.to_s.downcase.eql?('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

  # If this is a curl call, then get the params differently
  unless is_html
      params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
  end

  p params[:name]
end
```

If I call this using Curl, `params` has values, but when this is called via a web form, then `params` is `nil` and `params[:name]` has nothing. I spent several hours figuring out why it happens and asked help from other people, but no one could really find out what is going on.

One thing to note is, if I comment out this line:

```
params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
```

then `params` has the correct value for "web-form" posting.

Actually, the goal is to get the `params` value if this code is being called by CURL call, so I used:

```
params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
```

but it messed up the web-form posting. Can anyone solve this mystery?

Comment: It's possible that this isn't a case of Curl vs. web-page form, but rather a case of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` vs. `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: The `content_type` for both a Curl `POST` request, and the request from a browser using the form, is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd do it differently, by setting a hidden value in the form, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="webform" value="true">
```

then use it like:

```
if (params['webform'])
  # this is a request from the form
else
  # this is a request from Curl
end
```

If you see it you know the request came from your web-form. If `params['webform']` doesn't exist didn't it came from Curl.

I saved this to a file and ran it with Ruby:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/bucket' do
  params[:name]
end
```

Calling the running script using `http://localhost:4567/bucket?name=foo` displays:

```
foo
```

in the browser.

If I modify the source like:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/bucket' do
  params[:name]
end
```

restart it and load a simple HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:4567/bucket">
      <input type="hidden" name="webform" value="true"></input>
      <input type="input" name="name"></input>
      <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and input `foobar` and submit it, I see:

```
foobar
```

in the browser window.

If I change the script to:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/bucket' do
  if (params[:webform])
    'webform is set'
  else
    'webform is not set'
  end
end
```

and restart Sinatra and resubmit the form, I see:

```
webform is set
```

If I call it using Curl:

```
curl --data "name=foo" http://127.0.0.1:4567/bucket
```

I see this on the command-line as Curl's response:

```
webform is not set
```

If I change the script to:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/bucket' do
  if (params[:webform])
    'webform is set'
  else
    params[:name]
  end
end
```

restart the script, and call it with the Curl command again, I see:

```
foo
```

on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, I guess you misunderstood the question. Determining where the call is coming from is not the problem. It's about getting `params` in either cases.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand the question at all. I do misunderstand why you're going the long way around to determine the source of your request. I've never had a problem getting `params`, so you need to show more of the code you're using to set up your form and your DSL.

Comment: Tin man, did you try calling the same file by CURL and in the else part try printing params[:name]

Comment: Tin man, instead of printing 'webform is set' in the `else`, try printing `params[:name]`

Comment: Looks like the problem is pretty well triangulated now.